# How to properly extract point data from multi-raster grib file in R?

Tags: raster, r, extract, terra

I am trying to extract point data from grib files found at https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/hrrr.20210511/conus/.

These files consist of 170 or 173 layers (variables).  I want to extract the values of the cells at the points using terra:extract.  However, the extraction fails (there's something getting messed up between layers). Here are the lon/lat's I want to extract data at for each variable:

```
structure(list(Lon = c(-103.289, -96.6735, -96.9041, -96.76864, 
-102.4694, -96.6814, -97.7504, -99.6754, -96.4802, -103.0007, 
-96.8897, -101.8539, -103.9717, -101.253, -99.1134, -96.5849, 
-98.0301, -99.9537, -99.4601, -99.7122, -103.8278, -98.931, -102.1081, 
-101.7162, -100.115, -101.3448, -100.7805, -103.5606, -96.5302, 
-99.4156, -103.281, -100.0063, -97.9928, -100.7208, -98.5289, 
-96.762, -96.9218, -97.1024, -103.3793, -101.0841, -102.6745, 
-96.9188, -97.5154, -100.7435, -98.6938), Lat = c(45.5194, 44.3099, 
43.0526, 44.3252, 45.5183, 43.7316, 45.6796, 45.4406, 44.7154, 
44.0006, 43.7687, 43.9599, 43.4737, 44.9875, 45.0292, 44.0867, 
45.5735, 44.9895, 44.5256, 43.5938, 43.7343, 45.7163, 45.9189, 
43.1672, 45.6716, 45.9154, 45.7963, 44.6783, 44.5073, 43.7982, 
43.3784, 44.2912, 43.3841, 43.2002, 44.8579, 43.5048, 43.5033, 
45.1055, 44.4245, 45.4167, 44.5643, 44.304, 45.2932, 43.5601, 
43.7321)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -45L))

library(terra)

latlons <- terra::vect(latlon_df,geom=c('Lon','Lat'),crs="+proj=longlat")
latlons <- project(latlons,"+proj=lcc +lat_0=38.5 +lon_0=262.5 +lat_1=38.5 +lat_2=38.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m +no_defs")

grib_data <- terra::rast(path to grib downloaded grib file)
extracted_data <- terra::extract(grib_data,latlons)
```

The extracted_data is a mess and makes no sense.  It works fine if I do one layer at a time (but it takes much longer).

```
terra::extract(grib_data[[layer]],latlons)[,2]
```

What do I have to do to get a multi-layer extract to work?

Comment: What do you mean "extracted_data is a mess and makes no sense"? It is probably coming out as a list object, containing vectors or matrices, and can be processed using `lapply` but, since you do not provide further explication of the problem we can only speculate.

Comment: Actually, I did download one of grib files and test the problem, just had not gotten around to posting my answer. I was not able to recreate any problems and since you did not indicate a specific grib file there is no way to say that there is a problem with a specific file. Other than the nodata value -999 the values look resionable. Good luck with your issue. I would check your R and package versions.

Comment: Please edit the question and show us what your "mess" looks like. Although you have supplied links to data, its possible that we don't see any mess or we do see a mess that isn't the same as your mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did not work well, indeed, with terra 1.1-5; but it works with version 1.1-10.

```
# the value of "now" as it changes over time; you may need to change it to run this
now <- "hrrr.20210515"

ff <- c("hrrr.t00z.wrfnatf00.grib2", "hrrr.t00z.wrfnatf00.grib2.idx")
if (!all(file.exists(ff))) {
   url <- paste0("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/hrrr/prod/", now, "/conus/")
   for (f in ff) download.file(file.path(url, f), f, mode="wb")
}

library(terra)
latlon <- data.frame(lon=c(-103.29, -96.67, -96.9, -96.77, -102.47), 
                    lat=c(45.52, 44.31, 43.05, 44.33, 45.52))

latlons <- terra::vect(latlon, geom=c('lon','lat'), crs="+proj=longlat")
pts <- project(latlons, "+proj=lcc +lat_0=38.5 +lon_0=262.5 +lat_1=38.5 +lat_2=38.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371229 +units=m")
 
r <- rast(ff[1])
r1 <- r[[1]]
e1 <- extract(r1, pts)
e1 
#  ID 1[-] HYBL="Hybrid level"
#1  1                  91191.0
#2  2                  95623.8
#3  3                  97009.4
#4  4                  95659.8
#5  5                  91888.6
```

And

```
r2 <- r[[2]]
e2 <- extract(r2, pts)     
e2
#  ID 1[-] HYBL="Hybrid level"
#1  1                        0
#2  2                        0
#3  3                        0
#4  4                        0
#5  5                        0
```

Now for multiple layers with terra version 2.1-10

```
r123 <- r[[1:3]]
e123 <- extract(r123, pts)
e123 
#  ID 1[-] HYBL="Hybrid level" 1[-] HYBL="Hybrid level" 1[-] HYBL="Hybrid level"
#1  1                  91191.0                        0                        0
#2  2                  95623.8                        0                        0
#3  3                  97009.4                        0                        0
#4  4                  95659.8                        0                        0
#5  5                  91888.6                        0                        0
```

Comment: Thank you, Robert!